# Random codes found while inspecting my Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

```html
<style type="text/css">
  :root topadblock, 
  :root script[src^="http://free-shoutbox.net/app/webroot/shoutbox/sb.php?shoutbox="] + #freeshoutbox_content, 
  :root input[onclick^="window.open('http://www.FriendlyDuck.com/"], 
  :root img[alt^="Fuckbook"], 
  :root iframe[src^="http://static.mozo.com.au/strips/"], 
  :root iframe[id^="google_ads_iframe"], 
  :root div[jscontroller="U835zd"] + c-wiz[jsrenderer="YnuqN"], 
</style>
```

---

and more code was there... like these, almost 350 of them. Anyone know why?

Comment: It's quite likely that your site has been hacked. Best remove everything and restore the site from a known good backup.

Comment: its free plugins  or templates you have used in your  website.

Comment: verify your website here ,https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

Comment: Really? 
What should I do in future not to happen like this?

Comment: yes, it was a free theme

Answer (score 9):

In my case I have some code like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    :root topadblock,
    :root script[src^="http://free-shoutbox.net/app/webroot/shoutbox/sb.php?shoutbox="] + #freeshoutbox_content,
    :root input[onclick^="window.open('http://www.FriendlyDuck.com/"], 
    :root img[alt^="Fuckbook"],
    :root iframe[src^="http://static.mozo.com.au/strips/"],
    :root iframe[id^="google_ads_iframe"],
    :root div[jscontroller="U835zd"] + c-wiz[jsrenderer="YnuqN"], 
    :root a[href^="https://chaturbate.jjgirls.com/"][href*="?tour="], 
    :root a[href^="https://chaturbate.com/in/?tour="],
    :root a[href^="https://chaturbate.com/affiliates/"],
    :root .mod > ._jH + .rscontainer, :root a[href^="https://blackorange.go2cloud.org/"], 
    :root a[href^="http://www.1clickdownloader.com/"],
    :root a[href^="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?"],
    :root a[href^="https://awentw.com/"], 
    :root a[href^="http://adultfriendfinder.com/p/register.cgi?pid="],
    :root a[href^="https://www.popads.net/users/"], 
    :root iframe[src^="http://ad.yieldmanager.com/"],
    :root a[href^="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/"], 
    :root a[href^="https://sexdatingz.live/"], 
    :root a[href^="//bwnjijl7w.com/"],
</style>
```

For whom face this problem I should say it's because of **AdBlocker** Plugin* in Opera (at least in my case) So don't worry. If you wanna test you can:

- press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>E</kbd> and open "**Extensions**" page.
- Then find "**Opera Adblock**"
- Click on blue toggle button and **Disable** it.

Now you can refresh your website and as you can see all code disappeared.

Comment: Hi, I solved this by downloading the theme used from another website.

Comment: did you use Opera? or any other AdBlocker extension? Are you sure your website hacked? did you check via that link?

Comment: I'm using Google chrome.

Comment: if you are using adBlocker you can check other sites and lookup for "root" in your "Elements" section of your Google Chrome. take a look and let me know if it is still there or whatever. if it does, please click on "green thick" in left side of my answer and choose it as best answer. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

For all of the people who would like an answer to this question, here it is:
All of those links are links to sites that most likely download malware on your computer, and that code is there to immediately remove the malicious sites from the page before the site even has the chance to load properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30369620)

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was the Opera as mentioned in the answer - whitelisting the site stops adding the unwanted CSS to my site.